# how to enable MPI mpirun using firewalld in Centos 7

Tags: linux, mpi, firewall, centos7

I'm trying to make MPI run on a small cluster on Centos 7 OS. The firewall is preventing it from running. This is the error I get:

```
    $ mpirun -np 30 -hostfile hosts.txt mpi_sample_program/mpitest
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    A process or daemon was unable to complete a TCP connection
to another process:
  Local host:    marcher5
  Remote host:   ***.***.***.***.***
This is usually caused by a firewall on the remote host. Please
check that any firewall (e.g., iptables) has been disabled and
try again.
------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I disable firewall using : sudo systemctl disable firewalld, MPI works just fine.
I've been trying for a long week to add a rule that allows MPI to run without turning off the firewalld butit didn't work yet.
I was able to do it with sudo  iptables -A INPUT -s  -j ACCEPT and it worked. But now I have to use firewall-cmd because of Centos 7.
What do you suggest I do without compromising the security of the cluster. Should I add a rule to allow all traffic between my nodes?

My current firewall-cmd configuration is:

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-all
work (default, active)
  interfaces: eno1
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to add source using this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=work --add-source=[host_IP]
```

But still couldn't make the MPI application run correctly.
Then decided that the only way to enable MPI on this cluster is to make a rule to accept all traffic between the nodes. 
I ran those 2 commands.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -s  [server+IP] -j ACCEPT

firewall-cmd --reload
```

and it worked like  a charm.Not sure if this is the best solution security wise though.

Comment: IDK if it's the only/best solution, but what I can says is that usually, on clusters, the internal network isn't open to the outside, and therefore, since the only access point to the cluster is through the login or service nodes, those are the ones you have to manage access to and watertight secure

Comment: OK but what if a regular user entered the master node and tried to ssh to the slave nodes? given that he doesn't have an account on the slave nodes and he doesn't know their IPs. Is this a possible threat?

Comment: A regular user would have an account on the nodes, right? I think this is more related to http://serverfault.com/q/609148. Some sides reduce all limits and only increase them during startup of batch jobs, such that users without a batch allocation on the node can not make use of it. Otherwise: SSHing into a node with a wrong account, might slow down your network, but should not compromise the node. Non-knowledge of IPs is not something to rely on. Somebody on your master node will very likely figure out node IPs, if he really wants to.

Comment: This might also be of interest to you: https://lists.sdsc.edu/pipermail/npaci-rocks-discussion/2014-April/065061.html